# Entity Framework 6 code first existing database not generating Entity classes

Tags: entity-framework

Using Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server 2012. I've been happily using code first existing database to generate my data layer with no problems, until last week. For some inexplicable reason VS will not generate the Entity classes from my database tables (any solution, any projects, different databases and SQL instances).

The `DbContext` inheriting model class is generated containing the public `DbSet` properties for each table, also the `OnModelCreating` method which contains an `entity<>.Property` assignment for each field in each table.

Basically VS can talk to the database, read the schema, map and create everything except the entity classes. I am working on Win Server 2008R2 and applied a number of updates prior to the issue. I have since removed the updates, uninstalled then reinstalled VS but to no avail. Searching the web does not highlight anyone else who has encountered this. Can anyone help please? (VS 2013 is working fine).

Comment: So this is code first to an existing database and the reverse engineering process is breaking down or is it database first?

Comment: In the VS entity data model wizard the exact option i select is "Code First from database". As you say the reverse engineering breaks down. VS connects to the database, reads the schema, generates the model (inheriting from dbContext) class but then fails to generate the individual Entity classes.