# Entity Framework 6 Code First from database is not generating model classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to learn Entity Framework and I'm running into an issue where Code First from Database is not generating my model classes.  I'm using this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) to learn.

When I get to step 3, Reverse Engineer Model, everything works fine except that no model classes are created.  I only see my Context class.  Note, that I am also using a different database than in the example.  I'm using a database that already exists here at work.

To be clear, here are the steps I performed:

1. Right-clicked on Project and selected Add New Item.
2. Selected ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and clicked Add.
3. In the "Choose Model Contents" window, I select Code First from database (the last option), and click Next.
4. In the "Choose Your Data Connection" window I pick my connection from the dropdown, and click Next.
5. In the "Choose Your Database Objects and Settings" window I select a couple of tables from my database (I've also tried selecting all tables) and click Finish.

The window closes and after a couple seconds I get a new file in my project "ModelContext.cs".  This file contains the class that derives from DbContext.  It has all DbSet's of the tables I selected, however Visual Studio is complaining because those classes don't exist. From what I understand of the guide, those classes should have been generated.

My problem sounds exactly like the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658773/entity-framework-6-code-first-existing-database-not-generating-entity-classes) this person asked, but they received no answers.

A couple other details:

- The project is using .Net Framework 4.6.1 and it is a class library (I've also tried a console application project.
- I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3 (looking at my installed NuGet packages).
- The SQL database I'm connecting to is running SQL Server 2014 (Standard).
- I've tried this in Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and 2015, all with the same end result.  For VS 2012 and 2013 I did install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) so that the EF 6 tools would be available to me.
- I've tried this using a mySQL database as well but had the same thing happen.
- If I select "EF Designer from database" then the classes are generated fine.  I get a couple security warning prompts about running a text template but everything generates fine.
- I have downloaded the Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 extension and was able to generate the classes that way, but it generates everything instead of letting me select tables.
- I've tried this on my home computer and work computer and I get the same results.

Thumper asked for the schema of the table(s) I'm trying to pull in. I just tried with one table and I'm still getting the same result.

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LUCareManagers] (
   [CMName]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
   [UserID]     VARCHAR (25)  NULL,
   [CMID]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [Active]     CHAR (1)      NULL,
   [CMEmail]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
   [CMPhone]    VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
   [CMFax]      VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
   [Title]      VARCHAR (100) NULL,
   [EmployeeID] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_LUCareManagers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CMID] ASC)
);
```

Here is the DBContext that was generated:

```
public partial class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base("name=TestContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<LUCareManager> LUCareManagers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.CMName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.UserID)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.Active)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.CMEmail)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.CMPhone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.CMFax)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.Title)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LUCareManager>()
            .Property(e => e.EmployeeID)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: as you're describing it this is not code first. This is model first. With code first, you don't have a db created yet. EF does that based on the class model you create.

Comment: This is how you do code first migrations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra the linked article in the question refers to this process as "Code First from database". Confusingly..

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra Why does the article that I posted (the guide) show that I can do code first from an existing database?  This is also shown in a pluralsight video by Julie Lerman, who has written several books on Entity Framework.  Also if you go to the [msdn EF site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) it shows code first from a database as well.  From what I understand code first from existing database is basically a kick start to doing normal code first if your database exists.

Comment: Could you post the schema information for the two tables? Are you able to read/write data to these tables via queries through VS's Server explorer? Can you provide the auto-generated code from the Application Db Context class?

Comment: @Thumper Yes, I am able to read data from the tables through the server explorer.  I will update the post with the schema and dbcontext class.

Comment: Post has been updated to show the schema of a table I'm trying to pull in, as well as the resulting generated code.

Comment: So, I tried it again after closing and opening the solution and I got a class to generate but it won't work again.  I did notice that right after the step where I select the connection to use, my connection in server explorer has an red X next to it.  Right up to that step it is a green plus sign. I wonder if this is what is causing the issue?

Comment: From a brand new project (it targeted 4.5.1 by default and I changed it to 4.6.1), I wasn't able to repro this. I created a new database to a SQLServer Express instance on my local machine and added the table provided. Installed EF 6.1.3 and followed your steps, above. It generated an application context like the one above and it generated the model class. Have you tried isolating one table to a new DB instance and trying to repro?

Comment: The red X can mean the db no longer active. If you click to expand it, it should refresh the connection - it shouldn't impact your ability to generate the models. If you have to close and reopen your project to generate the models, that sounds like one of the behaviors of EF when you've never used it. I ran into a similar problem with my first use trying to move to code first from an existing DB. I never resolved the issue, but restarting Visual Studio, doing a full Clean & Rebuild seemed to resolve it.

Comment: Once you've generated those models, you should always clean and rebuild after you've updated the models, but before you run Update-Database against your project. Also, auto migrations are your friend.

Comment: @Thumper Would it matter if the database I'm connecting to is on a different machine?  The database is not on my computer, but on a dev server.  It is also not running on the standard sql port.

Comment: It should not matter. My preference is always to use a remote Sql Server - I just don't have a dedicated Sql Server at home. The only thing I can think of is if you have connected to this Db, before, with the same project - that could screw up EF's ability to auto-generate models. If you had an existing Connection String, other projects that used a different type of connection, or the like... you can hit problems that are rather difficult to debug.

Comment: @Thumper I must be doing something wrong, or have something installed incorrectly (or missing).  I created a brand new solution and went through the steps again, only to get the same result.  I also tried using a localdb database.  Whats confusing to me is that this happened to me in VS 2012, 2013 and 2015.  It also happened to me at home, so it makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but the steps are pretty clear.

Comment: I'd recommend targeting.NET 4.5 or 4.5.1, isolating the table in its own remote DB, and trying again. If this is an environment or permissions problem, then I don't know how much I can help, but if it's related at all to the rest of the remote DB, that could be why the problem is persisting. Local/offline DBs are a pain - I only use SQL Standard and SQL Express, when it comes to T-SQL.

Comment: @Thumper Thanks, I appreciate your help.  I tried a .NET 4.5 project and still no go.  I even tried on another computer at work.  Am I doing the correct steps as stated in my post?  Also, are you using VS 2012?

Comment: I am using VS2015 Community edition and SQL Server Express 2014. I use VS2015 Pro + Sql Server Standard at work. You are most-certainly following the correct steps. Have you tried creating a new DB on your SQL Server Standard instance, with just a single table... say dbo.MyTable with int Id Identity(1,1) and varchar(max) Value? If you can repro the issue with that, then it is likely some environment problem or permissions problem. Else, if you can't repro, then it's likely a schema-related issue.